# Type incorrectly inferred

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
implicit class RichString(s: String) {
  def !![T](createMessage: Long => T) = ()
}
case class SomeClass(i: Int, s: String, id: Long)
```

Why is it that this:

```
"some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", _)
```

Does not compile, throwing the following errors:

```
Missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "some string".$bang$bang(SomeClass(5, "test", x$1)))
 "some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", _)
                                       ^

Type mismatch;
 found   : cmd1.SomeClass
 required: Long => cmd1.SomeClass "some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", _)
```

But all of these compile just fine:

```
val f = SomeClass(5, "test", _)
"some string" !! f

"some string" !! ( SomeClass(5, "test", _) )

"some string" !! { SomeClass(5, "test", _) }
```

PS: this `"some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", _: Long)` also throws the type mismatch.

Comment: Infix notation works properly with one argument's methods. If you remove first two arguments it will work as you wish. Brackets introduce 1 argument methods...

Comment: With `case class SomeClass(id: Long)` and `"some string" !! SomeClass(_)` or `"some string" !! SomeClass(_: Long)` I still get a type mismatch. Only with `"some string" !! SomeClass` does it work. Also the !! method is an one argument method, it only receives a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the message says, `"some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", _)` is expanded as `x => "some string" !! SomeClass(5, "test", x)`, *not* `"some string" !! { x => SomeClass(5, "test", x) }`. So `!!` doesn't receive a function, it receives a `SomeClass`, which doesn't compile.

Comment: Other than using parenthesis is there any way to tell it to expand it to: `"some string" !! { x => SomeClass(5, "test", x) }`

Comment: I don't believe there is.